# Unsupervised Neural Network to Maximize a Function?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

Suppose I have vectors of dimension 1 x N {X_1...X_n} and {X_1' ...X_n'} where each X and X' are related but the relation is not able to be modeled by a function. I want to train a neural network by feeding it X_i and outputting Y_i with dimension N x 1, such that norm((X_i')(Y_i)) is maximized. The constraint is that Y_i has a norm of 1 (otherwise I will just use as large numbers as possible in Y_i).

I do not use X_i' as the inputs because they are not available in real life. I hope that when I test the neural network by feeding it {X_n+1 ... X_k}, it will output {Y_n+1 ... Y_k} where norm((X_n+1')(Y_n+1)) are maximized. Again, note that I only have {X_n+1'...X_k'} when testing, but not in real life where the neural network will be used.

I tried defining custom tensorflow or keras loss functions, but they don't seem to work. Also I tried using a neural network to first predict X_i' from X_i, but the performance is not very good.

A difficulty in this is to define a loss function that has no labels, and make neural network do backprop using this loss function.  Any ideas how this may be achieved?